# ErrorDocument with Rewrite and still get Referer

Tags: php, .htaccess, error-handling

What I basically want to do is redirect any 404 requests to `/404/` but then I would like to have it 'pull' the page to `index.php?error=404`, whilst leaving the URL as `/404/` - then I can get the referer using PHP (using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`).

I believe that the ReWrite rules should go prior to the ErrorDocuments, so my .htaccess file looks like the following:

```
RewriteRule ^404/$ /index.php?error=404
ErrorDocument 404 /404/
```

I know that I'm probably doing something fundermentally wrong with the above, since the 404 page/$_SERVER gets no referer URL (probably because of ErrorDocument).

The index.php page gets all the content routed through it (something very standard, I gather) and sends performs a header redirect to /404/ if/when a page/file is not found. Though if someone were to enter the URL into the browser incorrectly, I would like to get the original request, though since the page is being redirected anyway, should that be still be the referer in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you do it differently by directly using a `error.php` file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 error.php
```

You can then use that file as a proxy injecting all needed information into `index.php`. If you need to find out the apache status code (and additional useful information), take a look into the `$_SERVER` superglobal array.

Doing it this way gives you a better level of control and you can deal with server-differences easier in case you need to migrate your application from one server to another.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - I've decided not to redirect to the /404/ but will instead send a 404 header error in PHP and some text from the mini-CMS.